# Can ping MySQL from Eclipse but can't connect using JSP in Tomcat

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I can connect to a MySQL database from the Eclipse DataSource Explorer (ping successful) but running the code below in  Tomcat Server from Eclipse doesn't connect to DB. I get the "Unable to connect.." message.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
try {

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/LenderDetails", "root", "root");

out.println("connection ="+connection.toString());

if(!connection.isClosed())
%>
<% 
out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
connection.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
%>
<%
out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
}
%>
```

The URL in the JSP code is exactly the same as that in the DataSourceExplorer.

Eclipse Luna (4.4.2), Tomcat V7.0, mysql-connenctor-java-5.1.24-bin.jar, Java SE 7.

Any ideas why I can't connect from JSP or where I can find more details (Tomcat logs) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in .
Connection connection = `DriverManager.getConnection("com.mysql.jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/LenderDetails", "root", "root`");

just replace with .

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/LenderDetails", "root", "root");
```

You code will be look like following.

```
%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
try {

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/LenderDetails", "root", "root");

out.println("connection ="+connection.toString());

if(!connection.isClosed())
%>
<% 
out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
connection.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
%>
<%
out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
}
%>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  I tried "Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/LenderDetails", "root", "root");  but I still can't connect.

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: HI Praveen,  thank you for following up.  I fixed the connection issue by including the mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar into the Deployment Assembly of the Project.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by including the mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar into the Deployment Assembly of the Project.